# Application.LoadLevel("string") is obsolete

Tags: scripting, unity-game-engine

I got a code from someone that has lots of `Application.LoadLevel("whatever");`. Monodevelop says this is obsolete and that I should use `SceneManager.LoadScene` instead. How do I do that?

*Actually the `Application.LoadLevel("whatever");` line doesn't work unless I add the corresponding scene to the "build settings"*

Comment: Did you read this : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Comment: I've just read it. What about it? ..I try to use the line `SceneManager.LoadScene("whatever");` but the class cannot be found and it gives an error. Do I need to import something?

Comment: "whatever" should be an existing scene's name or a scene index you can find in the build settings (i.e. if scene is added to build, it's 'n-th' on list, that index). Give more details about your "whatever" so we can help

Comment: after your edit: then you sorted this out. consider deleting the question to keep SO clean or add your solution as an answer and accept it

Comment: How does the edit show that I sorted it out? I was clarifying. `"whatever"` is ofcourse the name of an existing scene. He uses the line allover the code with different scenes. Is it that hard that I need to mention it?  ...anyway I did figure it out without your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import `UnityEngine.SceneManagement` like this:

```
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

Then replace every `Application.LoadLevel("whatever");` with:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("whatever");
```

---

...It can also be done in one line:

```
UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("whatever");
```